# Jquery: Executing a function on keypress on google.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to capture the search query from google.com when the "enter" key is pressed.

I am using the following code to test that the event is actually being triggered:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {

    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});
```

This does not work when the focus is in the query box, but works fine otherwise I assume this is because an event is not being bubbled up by the auto-complete JS?  Any ideas what might be happening, and how I can get the keypress event to fire when the focus is on the query box, which is the case when a query is being entered?

Comment: Have you try to set the keypress event on the input box instead of the document ?  `$('#gbqfq')...`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `$(window).on('keyup', function() {});` of you can bind the same handler to the search input.

Answer (score 0):

Use "hashchange" event
It is triggered when triggered "auto-complete JS"

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function() {
    var query = getKeywordsFromUrl(document.location.href);
} );

function getKeywordsFromUrl(href) {
    var reStr = "google.com/search.*[&?]q=(.*?)(&.*)?$";
    var rx = new RegExp(reStr, 'm');
    if (rx.test(href)) {
        var parts = rx.exec(href);
        if (parts[1]) {
            var terms = decodeURI(parts[1]).split("+");
            return terms;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: So, something like this?

`$(window).on("hashchange", function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
    alert("You pressed enter!");
    }
    });`

Unfortunately, this breaks something. What data can I pass into the function here? And I couldn't find anything about hashchange in the Jquery API documentation. Can you please point me to some? Thanks

Comment: You should extract query from url

Comment: Ah, I see. So hashchange checks if the address has changed. Thanks!